# Synchronous Blocks in Node.js

Tags: node.js, http, synchronization

I want to know if it's possible to have synchronous blocks in a Node.js application. I'm a total newbie to Node, but I couldn't find any good answers for the behavior I'm looking for specifically.

My actual application will be a little more involved, but essentially what I want to do is support a GET request and a POST request. The POST request will append an item to an array stored on the server and then sort the array. The GET request will return the array. Obviously, with multiple GETs and POSTs happening simultaneously, we need a correctness guarantee. Here's a really simple example of what the code would theoretically look like:

```
var arr = [];

app.get(/*URL 1*/, function (req, res) {
    res.json(arr);
});

app.post(/*URL 2*/, function (req, res) {
    var itemToAdd = req.body.item;
    arr.push(itemToAdd);
    arr.sort();
    res.status(200);
});
```

What I'm worried about is a GET request returning the array before it is sorted but after the item is appended or, even worse, returning the array *as* it's being sorted. In a language like Java I would probably just use a ReadWriteLock. From what I've read about Node's asynchrony, it doesn't appear that `arr` will be accessed in a way that preserves this behavior, but I'd love to be proven wrong.

If it's not possible to modify the code I currently have to support this behavior, are there any other alternatives or workarounds to get the application to do what I want it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'm worried about is a GET request returning the array before it is sorted but after the item is appended or, even worse, returning the array as it's being sorted.

In the case of your code here, you don't have to worry about that (although read on because you may want to worry about other things!). Node.js is single-threaded so each function will run in its entirety before returning control to the Event Loop. Because all your array manipulation is synchronous, your app will wait until the array manipulation is done before answering a `GET` request.

One thing to watch out for then, of course, is if (for example) the `.sort()` takes a long time.  If it does, your server will block while that is going on. And this is why people tend to favor asynchronous operations instead. But if your array is guaranteed to be small and/or this is an app with a limited number of users (say, it's an intranet app for a small company), then what you're doing may work just fine.

To get a good understanding of the whole single-threaded + event loop thing, I recommend [Philip Roberts's talk on the event loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know! This means I'll probably have to use multiple servers for my project, but at least I won't have to deal with threading explicitly. And my array should be around 50 elements on average and around 500 elements in the most extreme scenarios, so blocking on that isn't a huge concern.